# How to get total cluster space quota in Cloudera distribution

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, webhdfs

How to get total cluster space quota in Cloudera distribution. One point here is,  some of the existing directories didn't set space quota.

Comment: Its not entirely clear what you mean. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: I want to get HDFS space quota for entire cluster. We haven't set space quota for some of the HDFS directories. When i fire the below commands, I got below output.
$ hadoop fs -count -q -h -v /
       QUOTA       REM_QUOTA     SPACE_QUOTA REM_SPACE_QUOTA    DIR_COUNT   FILE_COUNT       CONTENT_SIZE PATHNAME
        none             inf            none             inf       29.5 K        1.2 M              1.8 T /

Comment: The "quota" for the whole cluster is = hdfs capacity, I think.